# Canvas isn't resizing with window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a jFrame with a Canvas on it.  When I run my program in Windows XP/Vista and resize the window the canvas resizes proportionately along with the window.

However, in Ubuntu linux, when I compile the same java application and resize my window, the Canvas stays the same size.

What do I need to do to make my Canvas resize with my window in both Windows and Linux?  What is the deal with the discrepancy?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BallBounce");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        BallCanvas ballCanvas = new BallCanvas();

        frame.getContentPane().add(ballCanvas);
        frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**BallCanvas.java**

```
public class BallCavnas extends Canvas {
    public BallCanvas()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 400));
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        ... various gui controls are wired up here
    }
    ... rest of canvas code
}
```

---

Edit: My source code is zipped up here incase someone wants to take a look:
http://www.filedropper.com/ballbounce

I've done the suggestions made by Dave Ray, and it still isn't resizing the Canvas?  Remember, it resizes for me fine when I compile this java program and run it in windows.  Only in linux does it does this to me. I'm also running Java 6 Sun 1.6.0.10 JVM, if it matters.

[alt text http://img158.imageshack.us/img158/7642/screenshotww0.png](http://img158.imageshack.us/img158/7642/screenshotww0.png)

Perhaps my canvas is resizing by my **BufferStrategy/Graphics** aren't resizing ?

Edit 2: From the screenshot, it is definitely set to CENTER:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(ballCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

## Resolved

Apparently the "Canvas" was getting resized but I was doing something weird with it's buffer strategy that wasn't allowing IT to be resized.  I fixed it.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Simucal: I thought you only use to close questions, not ask them  ;-)  Interesting question btw :)

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, Did I close a question of yours or something? lol.  I sit in the #Stackoverflow IRC channel and get a live stream of questions.  If I see a dupe I try to identify it as so.. it is a PITA really.  Sometimes remembering back to all the Questions/Threads I have seen before can be tough

Comment: No, but  my guess is  it  was for you that they decided to add the "committee" close feature. You're always around. Actually it started with 3, but since you always took one seat, now 4 are needed. :) :)

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, lol.  Closing questions, and editing questions to make them have better grammar/layout (especially for non-native english speakers) are my two big contributions to the site.  I guess people don't like having their dupe questions closed, but I only do it for the good of SO.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, I never close borderline questions.. where people say that it isn't programming related.  I actually enjoy the fluff questions.

Comment: @Simucal: on your "Resolved" believe me or not, I always thought that was the problem see my comment:  "Start with empty canvas, then add the preffered size, then etc. etc. Chances are, the bug is on the paint method",  I have been there before :(

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, yea my render method had a subtle bug in it, retaining the same graphics object rather than getting a new one each render

Comment: I know it's been a while, but do you remember what you had to do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, the layout manager is just attempting to honor your preferred size.

I would:

A) remove the preferred just to see what happens ( not a very good idea anyway )

or

B) not use canvas in first place but JComponent.  After all Canvas is AWT component, and I not pretty sure how they work as today anyway. JComponent is a light weight component and since you're using a JComponent as container they would... mmhhh work better together?

Gee.. I'm giving voodoo programming suggestions now. Better get to work.

C) What have always worked for me. Make an small proof of concept, by adding step by step the stuff in my code.  Start with empty canvas, then add the preffered size, then etc. etc. Chances are, the bug is on the paint method :P

Good luck.

:)

Answer (score 2):

Use a border layout instead:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
BallCanvas ballCanvas = new BallCanvas();
frame.getContentPane().add(ballCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);            
frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Also get rid of setPreferredSize() in favor of frame.setSize() to set the initial size of the display.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?  I've changed it to a BorderLayout, and the canvas still retains it's original size after resizing.  Also, check my edit

Comment: @Simucal: Are you sure you put the ballCanvas in the CENTER?

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey, Yes, see my edit.  My code definitely has the canvas positioned in BorderLayout.CENTER.

Answer (score 2):

Another good solution is put the canvas into an JPanel,
like i did

```
    panel.add(new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
          // do not paint
        }

    }.add(capture));
```

and in the canvas function something like

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Dimension currentSize = getParent().getSize();
    int width = currentSize.width;
    int height = currentSize.height;
    if (offscreenImage == null || !currentSize.equals(offscreenDimension)) {
        // call the 'java.awt.Component.createImage(...)' method to get an
        // image
        offscreenImage = createImage(width, height);
        offscreenGraphics = offscreenImage.getGraphics();
        offscreenDimension = currentSize;
    }

    if (image != null) {
        offscreenGraphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    } else {
        offscreenGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        offscreenGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    //scratch image
    g.drawImage(offscreenImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

for example. This make it very simple. Take the parent Panel to fit to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed Dave's advice, esp. putting the ballCanvas in the CENTER, then you must be setting a maximum size for ballCanvas.